# Generate Branch IO links to two different applications?

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, branch.io

I have two different iOS/Unity applications (App A, App B) registered in [Branch IO](https://branch.io/) [dashboard](https://dashboard.branch.io/).
I want to build a webpage where I press a button and use Branch web API to generate a branch link (deep link) to App A. Then have a second button which will generate a deep link to App B.

Is this possible?

As far as I can tell everything is mapped 1:1 to the application with the "live key" when we init the JS Branch library with:-

```
branch.init('key_live_YOUR_KEY_GOES_HERE');
```

As you can see the Branch.IO documentation code example doesn't specify an application when creating the deep link:-

```
var linkData = {
  campaign: 'content 123',
  channel: 'facebook',
  feature: 'dashboard',
  stage: 'new user',
  tags: [ 'tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3' ],
  alias: '',
  data: {
    'custom_bool': true,
    'custom_int': Date.now(),
    'custom_string': 'hello',
    '$og_title': 'Title',
    '$og_description': 'Description',
    '$og_image_url':'http://lorempixel.com/400/400'
  }
};

branch.link(linkData, function(err, link) {
  console.log(link);
});
```

It's the same situation when the Unity applications startup and internally the Branch Unity sdk sets the key from within Branch.cs with:-

```
_setBranchKey(BranchData.Instance.liveBranchKey);
```

After this all Branch link creation is done through static functions so it's not possible to run multiple instances of this.

As far as I can tell from reading Branch documentation when generating links there's no way to specify the application you're trying to target (beyond the init keys). So it's locked down to a single application. Is this correct or is there another approach I don't yet know about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use the Branch API calls instead of using the Web SDK. Please see https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/deep-linking-api#section-creating-a-deep-linking-url. 
you can generate links for multiple apps by changing the 'Key' in the curl command.